# What file must I use for a animation render to post online?

Tags: rendering

I am experimenting with rigid bodies. I created a scene with a wrecking ball crashing through a pile of blocks. I tried rendering it in MPEG, but that makes it into a .dvd file. I want to post the end result on my facebook page, but it won't accept .dvd files. So what file format do I need to use to post online?

Answer (score 8):

Although there are [plenty of formats](http://www.facebook.com/help/218673814818907) that are currently supported by Facebook, when uploading to the online video sites, I personally like to choose **H.264** format, and simply choose the same in the **Preset** list in **Encoding** panel after that. Then give it a tweak if you want. The result format is ***.avi** in this case. Of course you can also try **Xvid** and others, as long as  they can be well supported by those sites. FYI and good luck.

[image]

Comment: I usually find that choosing the H.264 preset (like you do), and then selecting Quicktime as the format (instead of H.264 again), provides the most compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Below the **output panel**, there's an **encoding panel** which you will probably have to expand to see. If you choose **MPEG** as output format, the default encoding format is **.dvd**. You need to change this to a more suitable encoding. **For Facebook, I suggest MPEG-4**. That's it!